# Download file in java when Content-Length is incorrectly set?

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that downloads and uses a file at runtime. The file is valid as I can download it via the browser and open it up, etc. However my app kept reporting that the file is corrupted.

After investigation I discovered the server (which I have no control over) is returning an incorrect "Content-Length:" (~180 vs ~120000). The header is the culprit as I confirmed the issue by downloading the file with curl - which also resulted in a truncated file.

After some research I concluded that my use of `BufferedInputStream` to append to a `ByteArrayBuffer` is autosizing the byte array to the url connections content length. To circumvent this, I tried to use `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead, however this solved nothing.

Anybody know of a way to download a file if the Content-Length is incorrectly set? A browser can.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
public static void downloadFileFromRemoteUrl(String urlString, String destination){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        File file = new File(destination);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int curLength = 0;
        int newLength = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while((newLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            curLength += newLength;
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, newLength);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        android.util.Log.d("DB UPDATE", "Done downloading database. Size: " + byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unlikely. The browser also depends on Content-Length. Maybe the URL does not really points to the file; instead, it's an HTML page that embeds the file somehow.

Comment: IMO get the server to fix the Content-Length bug :P

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream `. Do away with that byte array output stream and write directly to the FileOutputStream. You don't need something intermediate. Not a solution for your problem though. Just better coding.

Comment: Have you openend the file to see if it is html instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After some research I concluded that my use of `BufferedInputStream` to append to a `ByteArrayBuffer` is autosizing the byte array to the url connections content length.

Nonsense. You are crediting those classes with paranormal powers. How could an output stream possibly become aware of the Content-length header? The `URLConnection`'s input stream is being terminated at the content-length. Correctly.

> To circumvent this, I tried to use ByteArrayOutputStream instead, however this solved nothing.

Of course not.

> Anybody know of a way to download a file if the Content-Length is incorrectly set?

You could use a `Socket` and engage in HTTP yourself, which is less trivial than it sounds. But the problem is at the server and that's where it should be fixed. Complain. Or else @Zong Yu is correct and the page is HTML containing JavaScript, say.

NB You don't need to read the entire file into memory:

```
while((newLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0)
{
    curLength += newLength;
    fos.write(buffer, 0, newLength);
}
```

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for using Sockets? I'm trying to give it a whirl but can't seem to make any progress. Having trouble figuring out how to create an input stream on an actual file at an HTTP url location...vs. the InetSocketAddress object used when I connect the socket.

Comment: Too broad. I suggest you look at the actual ~180 byte file to see whether it is indeed an HTML page, and if so post it here in your question.

Comment: On top of my ignorance and many variations on trying to solve this I failed to recognize it was a 301! The 180 byte file (as you were suggesting) was an HTML page! Wow, I feel stupid. Any thanks for keeping with me. My final solution was to use the `HttpURLConnection` instead and simply check to see if it was a 301...if yes, then update the url with the `Location`...which had the Content-Length I was looking for. BTW...for a bonus `HttpURLConnection`'s `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` didn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

My final "solution" was to realize I was dealing with a 301 redirect response and not the actual resource! I updated the section that handles my url, checking for a 301 and if exists, update the url. The new url contained the Content-Length that corresponded with the file I was downloading.

```
// start by creating an http url connection object
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// determine if this is a redirect
boolean redirect = false;
int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
        redirect = true;
}

// if it is, we need a new url
if (redirect) {
    String newUrl = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Fetch. Fetch is an in app download manager for Android. It's very easy to use. Find the GitHub page [here](https://www.github.com/tonyofrancis/fetch). The project comes with several demos that you can try out. Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Fetch, and it is open source.

Comment: But does it really ignore Content-length? And if so, why?

Comment: @EJP Fetch really only uses the content-length  to resume a paused download. But if you are downloading a file straight through it does not use the content length.

Comment: Hard to believe. (a) why? and (b) how does it know where the end of the file is? Does it turn off HTTP keepalive? And what does Content-length have to do with resuming paused downloads?

Comment: @EJP Many times servers return a content length of -1 and the file downloads successful. Content Length header is to only give you a heads up of how big the content is and can be used to request parts of a file data. We still have many old server running today that don't even return content length but you can download from them successfully. Once you open a connection with the server and get the input you just read it until the server does not return anything. That's when you know it's done.

Comment: We are discussing a content-length of ~180, not -1. A Content-length of -1 isn't sent at all, but it is *returned* by `HttpURLConnection.getContentLength()` when the header is *absent.* Not the same thing, and not the same issue as here. A content-length of 180 indicates that there are 180 bytes of response, and either it is an error at the server or more likely it suggests that the actual response returned is an HTML page with Javascript that URLConnection doesn't execute. Reading until the server doesn't return anything, by which I assume you mean a read timeout, isn't an indication of EOS.